# (rsExecutionNotFound) error on when running both 2005 and 2008 versions of Reporting Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I am running a web reports portal to access reports via the ReportViewer. Some reports are SSRS 2005 and others SSRS 2008. There is one ReportExecution reference and a ReportingServices2005 and ReportingServices2010 reference. If a user runs a 2005 report and then a 2008 report the reportexecution is lost.
Error message is: 
The report execution ifjzab55k5icxl4510oyfsmt has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)
I tried creating a separate ReportExecution to be used by the ReportingServices2010 reference but I get the same error.  P.S. I’m a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it. I used the **ReportServiceVersionEnum** to set ReportingServicesVersion and called the appropriate ReportExecution service depending on which version was used.